# Solvability of an integral equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, integral-equations

Is the following integral equation  solvable ?

$$ F(x)-\int^{1}_{-1} K(x,y)F(y)dy=f(x) $$ Where $$K(x,y)=\frac{\sin \gamma(x-y)}{\pi(x-y)}$$ and $$f(x)=e^{i\gamma x}$$
and $\gamma$ is a parameter.

Comment: Can you prove that the norm of the integral operator is less than $1$?

Comment: It may help to recognize that $K$ is related to the Direchlet Kernel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel